# Why is the answer text bow blank in my JQuery program after executing the addition function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am programming a calculator in JQuery mobile using Dreamweaver. I am currently working on the addition function of the program. When I click the add button, nothing appears.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="number">Number 1:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number" id="gnumber" value=""  />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="number2">Number 2:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number2" id="gnumber2" value=""  /
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="number3">Answer:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number3" id="ganswer" value=""  />
    </div>
    <div data-role="controlgroup">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" id = "gaddition" onClick = "generalAddition()">Add</a>
```

The script declaration is located at the end of the HTML code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Course Project.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function generalAddition(){
    index.getElementById(gnumber);
    index.getElementById(gnumber2);
    index.getElementById(ganswer);

    Double x = Double.parseDouble(gnumber.getText());
    Double y = Double.parseDouble(gnumber2.getText());
    ganswer.setText(x + y);
}
```

I have done research on how to properly include JavaScript code with JQuery Mobile. How do I get the program to perform an addition problem and insert it into the answer text box?

Comment: This is not JavaScript code.

Comment: `index.getElementById(gnumber);` etc ... why are you discarding the result? `.setText` - this not javascript (not even jQuery) - `Double x = Double.parseDouble` - as previous comment says, this isn't javascript

Comment: I'm sure your **developer** tools console is full of eels ... I mean, errors

Comment: Of course the “worst” part is `Double x` which looks like Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be another question about how javascript works. There are several mistakes, so I recommend you to do a javascript tutorial to get more knowledge about the language basics :).

Here are three links to javascript tutorials if you are interested in learning more about how it works:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/

https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Tutorials

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/

1. index.getElementById(gnumber)

   - do you define a global variable named index? Or do you actually mean `document`?
   - the parameter needs `"` -> `document.getElementById("gnumber")`
   - you have to assign the result to a variable `var gnumber = document.getElementById("gnumber");`
2. There is no global Double object in javascript.

   - do you use any library which provides this type?
   - in plain javascript you could use `parseFloat(<number>)` to get a floatingpoint number parsed from a string
3. there is no function `getText()` and `setText()` in javascript, you could use the `.value` property of the input objects, except you are using a library which provides the get and set methods you tried to use?
4. Is the javascript file really named `Course Project.js` with a space in the name, or is it in a subfolder `Course\Project.js`?

Here is a working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function generalAddition() {
            var gnumber = document.getElementById("gnumber");
            var gnumber2 = document.getElementById("gnumber2");
            var ganswer = document.getElementById("ganswer");

            var x = parseFloat(gnumber.value);
            var y = parseFloat(gnumber2.value);
            ganswer.value = x + y;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="number">Number 1:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number" id="gnumber" value=""  />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="number2">Number 2:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number2" id="gnumber2" value=""  /
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="number3">Answer:</label>
      <input type="number" name="number3" id="ganswer" value=""  />
    </div>
    <div data-role="controlgroup">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" id = "gaddition" onClick = "generalAddition()">Add</a>

</body>
</html>
```